# Java Get request for XML in Postoman

Tags: java, xml, postman

*Hi folks I am trying to get a customer in PostMan but unfortunately I cannot access the data the URL: I tried with customer/ only and also with customer/1*  `https://localhost:8181/iPCP/restServices/v1/user/customer/1`

*The Java code below:*

```
@GET
        @Path("/customer/{userId}") 
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        public Catalog getCustomers(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @QueryParam("userId") Long userId){

            IlsCustomer customer = getUserService().getUserById(IlsCustomer.class, userId);
            /*
            UserSearchCriteria<IlsCustomer> criteria = new UserSearchCriteria<>();
            criteria.setFirstName(firstName);

            List<IlsCustomer> customers = getUserService().getCustomers(0, 0, null, null, criteria);

            //ParkingInstanceSearchCriteria<IlsParkingInstance> piCriteria = new ParkingInstanceSearchCriteria<>();

            //getParkingService().getParkingInstances(0, 0, null, null, piCriteria);

            */
            Catalog catalog = new Catalog();

            /*
            for (IlsCustomer customer : customers) {
                catalog.add(customer);
            }
            */

            catalog.add(customer);

            return catalog;
        }
```

**The postman returns the following text, as you can see it is written that the page is not found error 404, can you tell me why this is so? I think the path is perfect:**

```
            <![CDATA[
if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale='en_US';PrimeFaces.settings.validateEmptyFields=true;PrimeFaces.settings.considerEmptyStringNull=true;}
//]]>
        </script>
        <title>The page cannot be found (404)</title>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/images/apple-touch-icon.png.xhtml?ln=primefaces-phq2&amp;v=3.1.4" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/jquery.history.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/perfect-scrollbar.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/layout.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/iPCP.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/pf-fixes.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="loginbodyorange">
        <div class="ipcp-warning-box">
            <div id="j_idt14" class="Card OvHidden HeiAutoOnMobile ui-widget spacer-top3">
                <div class="CardWrapper">
                    <div class="CardTextContainer">
                        <div class="CardContent">
                            <div class="spacer-top3">
                                <i class="fa fa-files-o Fs100 ipcp-icon-warning"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Fs30 ipcp-icon-warning">The page cannot be found (404)
                    </div>
                            <div class="Fs20">
                                <div id="msgs" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite" data-global="false" data-summary="data-summary" data-detail="data-detail" data-severity="all,error" data-redisplay="true"></div>
                                <p>You tried to access a page that does not exist. Please check the entered URL. 
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/> If you reached this site following a link, this link is probably outdated, if possible we will update this link as soon as possible.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="j_idt14_footer" class="CardFooter">
                            <button id="errorHome" name="errorHome" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left OrangeButton ui-button-big" onclick="window.open('/iPCP/home','_self')">
                                <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-home fa-fw"></span>
                                <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Click here to get back to the beginning.</span>
                            </button>
                            <script id="errorHome_s" type="text/javascript">
//
                                <![CDATA[
PrimeFaces.cw("Button","widget_errorHome",{id:"errorHome"});
//]]>
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-top2">
                </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/iPCP/javax.faces.resource/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js.xhtml?v=3.1.4"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" id="j_idt33">
//
            <![CDATA[

    $('input.floatlabel, textarea.floatlabel, .floatlabel.ui-inputnumber input.ui-inputfield').floatlabel( {
        paddingOffset                   : '0px',
        marginOffset                    : '0px'
    });

//]]>
        </script>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//
        <![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (/(\?|\&)cid=\d+/.test(document.location.href)) {            
            History.replaceState(null,null,document.location.href.replace(/cid=\d+/,"nocid=true"));
        }
    });

//]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a @Path annotation on your class ?

Comment: yes it is this one: @Path("/v1/user/")
public class UserRestService extends BaseRestWebService {

Comment: Are you sure the document root is  /iPCP/restServices  and not simply iPCP ?

Comment: Lauren - Yes, I am completely sure because I am accessing to products the same way and I do not understand even if the method does not work correct I shold see something different...

Comment: Could you provide web.xml? Also, are you sure, that https is properly configured?

Comment: The problem is solved in was that I was running wrong project because I have 10 versions of 1 project and the version was not correct... thank you!